# How to open an app in my flutter app without making it fill up the whole screen?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a flutter app that can open Instagram, twitter or any other app.

But, I don't want the app to fill up the whole screen. I also want to display the app inside of my own app like this:

[image]

Is there a way to display an app like this?

Comment: I don't think this is supposed to work. Perhaps you mean https://medium.com/sentio-superbook/how-to-enable-multi-window-in-android-o-678cced03db2 ?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

- Opening other apps require their permission.

This means that you need development access for those apps.

[Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/)

[iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

- The way an app is displayed is handled by the OS and that functionality is not accessible for iOS and Android developers to be customised.